# Angular 8, get current user in authentification service

Tags: angular

[What I get from the the backend api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsWh6.png)

I'm trying to get the current user as an observable in authentication service, so I can display the user name in any component that subscribes to the `authService`.

Everything works fine, but I can't get the current user.

Authentication service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http'
import { Router } from '@angular/router'
import { User } from '../models/user'
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthentificationService {
  private _registerUrl = "http://localhost:3000/api/users/register"
  private _loginUrl = "http://localhost:3000/api/users/login"
  private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<any>;

  public currentUser: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {}

  register(user): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>(this._registerUrl, user)
  }

  login(user): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>(this._loginUrl, user)
      .pipe(map(userInfo => {
        localStorage.setItem('token', userInfo.token)
        this.currentUser = userInfo.user
        return userInfo.user
      }))
  }

  public getCurrentUser(): Observable<any> {
    return this.currentUser;
  }
```

`onSubmit` method of `login` component:

```
onSubmit() {
    const infoUser = {
      email: this.email,
      password: this.password
    }

    //reset alert on submit
    // this.alertServ.clear()

    this.authService.login(infoUser).pipe(first()).subscribe(loggingData => {
      this.router.navigate(['/'])
    },
      err => {
        this.errors = err.error
        this.errorMessage = "verify email or password"
        this.alertServ.error(this.errorMessage)
      }
    )
  }
}
```

modified  login method :

```
login(user): Observable<any> {

    return this.http.post<any>(this._loginUrl, user)
      .pipe(map(userInfo => {



        localStorage.setItem('token', userInfo.token)

        console.log(userInfo)
        this.currentUserSubject.next(userInfo)
        return userInfo



      }))



  }

  public getCurrentUser(): Observable<any> {


    return this.currentUserSubject.asObservable()
```

Comment: What is an error? What mean 'but i cant get the current user'?

Comment: In the login(user) method, why do you have 2 return statements? Since you are assigning userInfo.user to the currentUser, you don't have to return it again. Try removing return userInfo.user line.

Comment: The backend api returns a json object  as you can see in the screenshot , witch contains another json object with the logged user infos  , i'm new  to rxJs so i dont know how to return the user as an observable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to instantiate your user subject and pump the value into it using its `next(..)` method.

```js
private currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null); // initializing with no user object since logged out

...

login(user): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post<any>(this._loginUrl, user).pipe(
    map(userInfo => {
      localStorage.setItem('token', userInfo.token);

      this.currentUserSubject.next(userInfo.user); // <-- pump the value in here

      return userInfo.user;
    })
  );
}
```

Finally, in your `getCurrentUser()` method you want to return the observable version of your subject:

```js
getCurrentUser(): Observable<any> {
  return this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
}
```

Comment: @chedlichris can you provide details of what your code looks like now. You will not get the same error you have in your post if you make these changes. The reason you were getting the error you stated is because your `this.currentUser` variable was not an observable. Doing what is posted above solves that problem (note that the `getCurrentUser()` method is not using your `this.currentUser` variable), along with setting up/populating the subject which your code above was not doing.

Comment: `login(user): Observable<any> {

    return this.http.post<any>(this._loginUrl, user)
      .pipe(map(userInfo => {



        localStorage.setItem('token', userInfo.token)

        console.log(userInfo)
        this.currentUserSubject.next(userInfo)
        return userInfo



      }))



  }

  public getCurrentUser(): Observable<any> {


    return this.currentUserSubject.asObservable()
`

Comment: @chedlichris Did you modify the line to initialize the `currentUserSubject` variable as shown in the code above? If not, you will get an error in your `login` method when it attempts to call `next()` and in your `getCurrrentUser()` method when it attempts to call `asObservable()`.

Comment: yess `private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<any>`

Comment: @chedlichris That is not what the line should be. Please see the code above. What you have there is not initializing the variable. It is simply stating that the variable should have the type of `BehaviorSubject<any>`

Comment: sorry for making you headaches , i'm  new to all of this stuff

Comment: @chedlichris It is important to understand what `private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<any>` does in typescript. It does not initialize a variable with a value. The syntax `variableName: VariableType` is stating that there is a variable with name `variableName` and type of `VariableType`. If it is not set to anything, the variable is `undefined`.

Comment: @chedlichris By changing the line to `private currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);`, you are setting the variable to an instance of `BehaviorSubject<any>`. Typescript infers the type to be `BehaviorSubject<any>` unless you tell it is a different type (e.g. `private currentUserSubject: Subject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);` where typescript will see the type as `Subject<any>` instead of `BehaviorSubject<any>`).

Comment: hey do you still here ? i have a question